# Look up a value from a different row within a SELECT or UPDATE

Tags: mariadb

I have a large database filled with plant names. I have a column with the species (Latin) name, and one with the Dutch name. Unfortunately, the Dutch names are not complete.

```
id      species                 name_nl 
2475    Ligustrum               Liguster            
2476    Ligustrum delavayanum   Bolliguster             
2477    Ligustrum japonicum     Japanse liguster                                    
12300   Ligustrum ibota         ...     
13937   Ligustrum sinense       ...         
13938   Ligustrum 'Vicaryi'     ...
```

A small botanical explanation before I continue: A species name consists of a genus (Liguster) and an epithet (delavayanum). My list has a kind of default name for a genus (in this case id 2475), which I want to use to fill in missing Dutch names.
My strategy is to use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the genus from the species name, and use that to look up the generic name, and update the row with that. So I should end up with this:

```
id      species                 name_nl 
2475    Ligustrum               Liguster            
2476    Ligustrum delavayanum   Bolliguster             
2477    Ligustrum japonicum     Japanse liguster                                    
12300   Ligustrum ibota         Liguster                        
13937   Ligustrum sinense       Liguster                            
13938   Ligustrum 'Vicaryi'     Liguster
```

I tried this bit of SQL (I am using SELECT instead of UPDATE for now):

```
SELECT `species`, `name_nl`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`species`, ' ', 1) as genus, ( SELECT name_nl WHERE species LIKE genus ) FROM `names_nl` WHERE name_nl='';
```

It's close, but `SELECT name_nl WHERE species LIKE genus` sticks to its own row, which obviously produces NULL.
I want it select id 2475 every time it's called instead. Is that possible, and if yes: how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of the column name_nl that you want to fill? Is it NULL or ''?

Comment: @forpas Just empty.

Comment: Join 2 copies of your table - one complete and anoter with defaults only.

Comment: Empty could be NULL or `''` or `'   '` or similar.

Comment: @fopas OK, it's ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.species, COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.name_nl, ''), t2.name_nl) name_nl
FROM names_nl t1
JOIN names_nl t2 ON t2.species = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.species, ' ', 1);
```

and

```sql
UPDATE names_nl t1
  JOIN names_nl t2 ON t2.species = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.species, ' ', 1)
SET t1.name_nl = t2.name_nl
WHERE TRIM(t1.name_nl) = '';
```

Comment: Seems to work as well, and almost instantaneously: 6429 rows affected. (Query took 0.3053 seconds.) However, I need to figure out which 93 rows this query didn't affect, but are affected by @forpas' version.

Comment: @DiederikSlob Simply compare the rows processed by forpas' query and by my query, find `id` values which are not processed by my query and find the case of difference.

Comment: @forpas does something I didn't ask for, but which is very nice: his query also gets the Dutch name for a variety of a known species. So Echinocactus grusonii has the Dutch name Schoonmoedersstoel, which is now added to Echinocactus grusonii 'Inermis'. Would it be possible to add this to your query? I tried to change SUBSTRING_INDEX, but getting the second part of a name isn't trivial, it seems.

Comment: Nevermind the request, the coin dropped. I first run the UPDATE with SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.species, ' ', 2), which captures all the occasions where there is a  species match. Then I run the original UPDATE which mops up the genus matches. This combines your speed and an even better result than forpas' version. Superduper THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data you can self join the table with the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause to get the default genus and update with that the empty column values:

```
UPDATE names_nl n1
INNER JOIN names_nl n2 ON n1.species LIKE CONCAT(n2.species, ' %')
SET n1.name_nl = n2.name_nl 
WHERE n1.name_nl = '';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5192d4da225657f901e4439fac0c4bfd).

Comment: The good news: it works. The bad news: 6522 rows affected. (Query took 205.6452 seconds.) I will try to figure out how your query works, though. The bit where you add an alias is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion - use a regular expression to extract the first substring from the species name:

```
select nl1.species, coalesce(nl1.name_nl, nl2.name_nl)
  from names_nl nl1
  left outer join names_nl nl2
    on nl2.species = regexp_substr(nl1.species, '[^ ]+', 1, 1)
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=783c8169bc88e7b6a620e1d574170ddb)

Comment: MariaDB doesn't seem to have the full implementation of regexp_substr. Alas.

Comment: Answers should conform to the capabilities of the tags supplied on the question. Since this question is tagged for [mysql] any answers will be written in the expectation that [mysql] is the tool in use. For MariaDB, however, you can just drop the `...1, 1` in the REGEXP_SUBSTR call and it'll work fine. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=fbb3e6147e32728efa0d528f2356d40e)

Comment: I just realised I have MariaDB by figuring out what the problem was. Thought it was some fancy name for MySQL when I installed it and never bothered about it again. I will better my life, Sir!